# How do you use the require function on your website?

Tags: javascript, express, visual-studio-code

I set up a page for routes that I tried to run on Visual Studio Code's live server but it doesn't work because of the require functions. I need to use this for the routes, especially to view people's profile pages. (This works perfectly when I run everything through terminal using node routes.js and having all my js and css files linked using the static directory)

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

app.get('/user=:username', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/profile.html'));
});
```

I searched "How to use require function on local server" and "How to use require function on website" but couldn't find anything after scrolling to the 3rd/4th page for each query. Any help? Thanks, hopefully I worded everything correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Require is not actual vanilla JavaScript syntax, it is just what `CommonJS` uses in order to import and use modules. If you want to import modules in your vanilla JavaScript web application, you can use the ES6 modules syntax.

**Note:** You will probably need to transpile this code in order for it to work on older browsers because this is ES6 syntax.

Firstly, because you are trying to import path, you need to make sure you have **node types installed in your application**, so please run this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

**Now, you can import path using:**

```
import * as path from 'path';
```

**Secondly, to import express:**

```
import express from 'express';
```

Also, you can use the following command if you need some help with scaffolding:

```
npx express-generator your-project-name --no-view
```

**Edit:**

Some more info:

1. All imports should be at the very top of your JS file before you write any other JS Code.
2. You need to specify the script type to be module :  `<script type="module" src="app.js"> </script>` in your HTML.

Here, this will come in handy: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-es6-modules-and-why-theyre-important-a9b20b480773/

Comment: Thanks Link! No idea why that info isn't very easy to find but thanks! Quick question, its saying "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module", along with this, I added import app from 'express';. Is there another issue I overlooked?

Comment: It's probably because where you might've placed the imports. All imports should be at the very top of your JS file before you write any other JS Code. Also make sure you specify the script type to be module :  `<script type="module" src="app.js"> </script>` in your HTML. Here, this will come in handy: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-es6-modules-and-why-theyre-important-a9b20b480773/

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the link! I'll finish everything else, enjoy your night :)